# I'd like to verify that $\{[0], [1]\}$ is an abelian group under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since $[0][1] = [0] \in \mathbb Z_2$, this ring is closed under multiplication.

Let $[1]$ be identity: $[0][1] = [0]$ and $[1][1] = [1]$.

$[0][1] = [0 \cdot 1] = [1 \cdot 0] = [1][0]$ so commutativity holds.

If we assume $\mathbb Z_2$ is a ring, associativity is given.

I am having difficulty showing there's inverse element in $\mathbb Z_2$. What could possibly be the inverse of $[0]$? Please, elaborate on this. Thanks.

Comment: $[0][0]=[0]$ and $[0][1]=[0]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{[0],[1]\}$, we conclude that $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}_2,\ [0]x=[0]$. Since $[0]\neq[1]$, we conclude that $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}_2,\ [0]x\neq[1]$. Doesn't this show that $[0]$ has no inverse?

Comment: The additive zero does not have a multiplicative inverse in a ring.

Comment: What I am doing is I am assuming $\mathbb Z_2$ is a ring and trying to show that it's also an abelian group under multiplication so that $Z_2$ is a field. Maybe some of that doesn't sound correct?

Comment: In a field, the *non-zero* elements form a group under multiplication. (The zero element in a ring only has an inverse in the trivial ring with only one element.)

Comment: You need to reread the definition of a field.

Comment: @RobArthan, then just showing  $\{[1]\}$ is an abelian group under multiplication is enough?

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z_2},+)$ isn't the same as $(\mathbb{Z_2^{*}},(*))$

Comment: @user315002: yes, the multiplicative group of the two-element field is the trivial group with one element.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be very difficult. {[0],[1]} is not a group under multiplication.